wifi adpater not found 22.04
"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found." It then prompts me to ensure the Wi-Fi adapter is plugged in and turned on. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 hoping to resolve this issue, but it didn't help. I also tried running the command sudo lshw -class network in the terminal. Initially, it showed "usb," but that quickly disappeared, and there was no output afterward. Running lsusb produced the following output:
